# Autofac InstancePerHttpRequest using Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, autofac

What is the **Ninject** equivalent of the following **autofac** code:

```
builder.RegisterType<WebWorkContext>().As<IWorkContext>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Basically I want to share some settings such as current working language, username, currency format for a specific user within the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Binding to ninject kernel (e.g. in `global.asax`)**

```
kernel.Bind<IWorkContext>().To<WebWorkContext>().InRequestScope();
```